# Galleria speed up interval by button

Tags: javascript, galleria

I'm trying to speed up (or slow down) the Galleria imageslider by button.

Is there any way to get te current interval time and count it +500?

My code currently:

```
   function speel(){

      var gallery = Galleria.get(0);
      //GET CURRENT INTERVAL var current = ..Interval
      var newspeed= current speed + 500
      gallery.play(newspeed);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current interval

```
var current = gallery._playtime;
```

Since 1.2.5 you can use

```
gallery.setPlaytime(newspeed);
```

instead

```
gallery.play(newspeed);
```